# Why doesn't my button appear when i set the CLProximity range?

Tags: uibutton, cllocationmanager, ibeacon

My project involves the device (iPad) and 2 physical beacons. It works in a way when my device enters the immediate range of each beacon (with different minor value), a button will appear for each specific beacon. However the problem here is that the buttons stop appearing once I listed the if-statement for the beacon.proximity condition. All help is appreciated!

```
-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didRangeBeacons:(NSArray *)beacons      inRegion:(CLBeaconRegion *)region
{
CLBeacon *beacon = [[CLBeacon alloc] init];
beacon = [beacons lastObject];

self.majorLbl.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", beacon.major];
self.minorLbl.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", beacon.minor];

if ([self.majorLbl.text  isEqual: @"1"])
{
    if ([self.minorLbl.text isEqual:@"10"])
    {
        if (beacon.proximity == CLProximityImmediate)
        {
            _movieBtn1.hidden = NO;
        }
        else if ([self.minorLbl.text isEqual:@"3"])
        {
        if (beacon.proximity == CLProximityImmediate)
        {
            _movieBtn2.hidden = NO;
        }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Two possible issues:

1. Your if statement is mismatched so that you can never detect the beacon with minor 3.  Try changing it to:

   ```
   if ([self.majorLbl.text  isEqual: @"1"])
   {
       if ([self.minorLbl.text isEqual:@"10"])
       {
           if (beacon.proximity == CLProximityImmediate)
           {
               _movieBtn1.hidden = NO;
           }
       }
       else if ([self.minorLbl.text isEqual:@"3"])
       {
           if (beacon.proximity == CLProximityImmediate)
           {
               _movieBtn2.hidden = NO;
           }
       }

   }
   ```
2. If both beacons are detected at the same time, you will only take action on one because of this statement:

   ```
   beacon = [beacons lastObject];
   ```

Instead, loop through all detected beacons in the array and execute the same logic for each.

Finally, take care that your beacons really are getting an *immediate* proximity estate and aren't slightly further away.  I would add an else clause for this case and log a message for this condition to aid in debugging.

Comment: David's advice is good as always, but I would advise against converting the beacon major and minor values to strings, storing those strings in a label, and then interrogating the text contents of the label. Labels are view objects, and shouldn't be used to save state data. Also, converting to strings and then comparing strings is error-prone. Instead use the integerValue method on the beacon.major and beacon.minor properties and do numeric comparisons.